# google action smart home account linking not working

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have added a google action for a smart home app. When trying to add devices with my test application, I do get the error message that the "Cloudn't update setting. Check your connection".

The app uses authorization code as grant type. The flow seems to be completed on my server side. The last step, i.e. requesting the access token, is correctly answered (see below).

Is there any way to see why google is not linking the account? BTW logcat didn't indicate any problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

> [  /  ] LoggingFilter:132 -Request: request
> id=34; method=POST; content type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
> uri=/oauth/token; payload= 2017-08-23 04:22:05 INFO
>
> [  /  ] LoggingFilter:149 -Response: request id=34;
> payload={"access_token":"b77205db-1dea-427a-b165-09dfd37af1f1","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"b92ee03c-475c-4c5b-a606-fb847be9386a","expires_in":498,"scope":"auth"}

It seems not to be a linking problem. Grepped from logcat:

```
08-28 08:15:48.211: I/ActivityManager(1499): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=assistant-handoff://complete/?result_code=SUCCESS&result_message=Accounts+now+linked. flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.handoff.BrowserReturnActivity (has extras)} from uid 10047
08-28 08:15:48.579: I/ActivityManager(1499): START u0 {dat=assistant-handoff://complete/?result_code=SUCCESS&result_message=Accounts+now+linked. cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.handoff.BrowserControlActivity} from uid 10030
```

so also from the assistent point of view the linking seems to work.

Comment: Please see this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs/issues/26

Comment: Thanks for the link. The issue does not provide any solution so far. If I got it right the reporter tries now to publish the project and hopes that it is only a testing issuse.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't resolve your issue, but it is the same issue and it will be useful to go there for triaging.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I added also a post there.

Answer (score 0):

This has recently been fixed with a server-side update.